# Ruby on Rails how does this route not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my config > routes I have:

```
#Service Routes
  match "services" => "services#index"
  match "startsingleservice" => "services#start_single_service"
  match "stopsingleservice" => "services#stop_single_service"
  match "zookeeperreindex" => "services#show_zookeeper"
```

The first 3 work, no issues no problems. And all four are in the same file def/functions whatever you wanna call them. Are in the same file. Where again first 3, work awesome. Adding that new guy there, zookeeper just doesn't wanna work I get

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'show_zookeeper' could not be found for ServicesController

the function zookeeperreindex is almost a mirror of the actual index def in the same file, changed for the needs of redisplay as I only want a JSON output for that one. But bottom line is I changed the routes to match, I know the function is working for the most part, and I am not seeing where I could be messing this simplicity up, I've also restarted the server itself to ensure it wasn't that

***Edit***

In replying with code from the controller which by the way did "show_zookeeper" defined right.. I realized I had a misplaced "end" tag.. So, in moving that the route worked.

Comment: Please paste the ServicesController code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in your `ServicesController` (app/controllers/services_controller.rb)

You never define a method `show_zookeeper`. My guess is that you define a method `zookeeperreindex` instead of `show_zookeeper`.

Why don't you link the contents of that file? You should see something along the lines of,

```
class ServicesController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    ...
  end
  def start_single_service
    ...
  end
  def stop_single_service
    ...
  end


  def show_zookeeper # <---- This one is missing

  end
end
```

The way the routes work the part after the `=>` determines the controller and action. For example "services#start_single_service" will be mapped to `:controller => ServicesController`, and `:action => start_single_service`.

Thus the final call will be `ServicesController.start_single_service`

Look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more info